# Cursor not appearing in chrome in nested contenteditable structure when css after is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am working on a HTML which has `contenteditable` with value `true` wrapped inside div with contenteditable `false`.
The HTML structure is:

```
<div contenteditable=false>
    <div contenteditable=true>
        <p>Abc</p>
        <p>Def</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/gxbqujdw/1/

Replication Steps:
Open in Chrome

1. Click after @ in line with text 'Def'
2. Now click after @ in line with text 'Abc'. Cursor doesn't appear.
3. If now I click to the left of @ in text 'Abc', cursor appears. Now click to the right of @, cursor appears as desired position to the left of @.

In Firefox and Edge it works as desired, cursor always appears on left when clicking to the right of @ in any line. It will be great if some one can suggest any html or Css solution, otherwise javascript or jquery will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the Css to fix this issue.

You can use Display property in `p:after.`.

[Please check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gxbqujdw/2/)

Comment: Yes adding display:display-inline solves the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `:after` to `position:absolute` seems to solve the issue (tested in Chrome):

```
p:after {
content:"@";
position:absolute;
cursor:text;
z-index: -1;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/47heavn3/)

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem but adding position absolute is distorting my layout in actual scenario.